# How can my PHP code run when i submit a HTML form

Tags: php, python, html, flask, exec

I am trying to make a website using python and in flask I have a webpage that has a submit button, when the button is pressed I need it to run a python file I have called Answers.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, send_from_directory

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/help', methods=["GET","POST"])
def help():
    return render_template("help.html")
```

the HTML code on the page is this and i am trying to get when the button is pressed it runs a php script that outputs the value from a separate python file, the output text.

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="sub" value="Hello world">Submit 
call</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried this php code in the same file as the HTML but nothing is output when I press the button, i'm new to php so i'm not sure what the problem is.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sub']))
    {
        $result = exec("Python Path Answers.py /tmp");
        echo $result;
    }
?>
```

Comment: In order to locate the bug, add 'echo "submit done.";' in the php's IF condition. If it appears after submitting the form, the problem is with the python's function.

Comment: I'm still wondering if I understood this correctly: you are running a Flask server in Python, which should run a PHP script, that then runs another Python script?

Answer (score 1):

The php script never gets referenced in the html page!

```
<form action="" method="post"><!-- action there is empty! -->
```

You should reference the php script in the `action` attribute of the `<form>` tag, like so:

```
<form action="myscript.php" method="post">
```

Comment: it still doesn't show up, I have tried calling it as a php file but it still doesn't show up

Comment: JayE, try what Ofir Baruk said first, namely comment out the content of the if in the php script and add a `echo "submit done";` instead to check wether it gets called at all or not; if the "submit done" appears in the page, then there's an ulterior problem, namely in the `exec`; in fact I can see there that the name of the python script has got spaces in it, and maybe it does not get called at all... You can switch on the php debug mode too with a `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`
`error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of the php script